# py serial and it's splitting my results between lines

Tags: python, pyserial

I am having some issues with py serial and it is splitting my results between the lines, any idea how to fix this?
e.g. It should output a 31 at the moment.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=4)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
count=1

while True:
    for line in ser.readline():

        print(chr(line) )

ser.close()
```

This is what it outputs:-

```
connected to: COM3
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
```

Answer (score -1):

I spent a few more hours on it and i have a solution I'm not going to explain it but here it is. I'm going to go sleep now.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
count=2
val = 0
data = 0
while True:
    val = ser.readline()
    if len(val) > 1:
        print(str(val)[2:-1])
ser.close()
```